# How to setup namespaces based on folder structure for Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I downloaded Unity 20.2 and want to use namespaces for my code. I modified my project settings to this

[image]

In the editor I now have this folder structure for my code

[image]

The problem is that the created script `Test` has the namespace `Sources` although I would expect it to be `Sources.Scripts`. I also tried `Assets.Sources` but it still is not able to create `Assets.Sources.Scripts` from it.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: why downvote? please comment at least

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a class in Visual Studio, then it automatically gets the namespace from the folder structure. Like `assets.scripts.something`. Just create classes in the correct place and you will get all needed namespaces.

Comment: hey, I tried it with Rider. Currently I have the value `Sources` in the settings. Unfortunately it still uses the namespace `Assets.Sources` for new files. Rider tells me to fix that namespace, but Rider wants it to be `Assets.Sources.Sources.Scripts` which is weird too.

Comment: I tested it with the value `Assets` now and Rider fixes the namespace from `Assets` to `Assets.Sources.Scripts` which is correct.

Comment: but that Unity feature is weird then ... it is not working as expected ...

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to describe a situation with some packages in a project to explain this:

Imagine a project in Unity3D with a directory structure like this:

- Assets

  - Resources
  - Scenes
  - Source/Scripts

    - UI

      - Buttons
      - Modals

**Namespaces convention in this case is driven by the programming language used (C#)** in the project (First letter in uppercase, matching the name of the folders).

**I suggest you to ignore the directory path until the "Source" or "Scripts" folder** when you are choosing the namespaces of your packages. Then in this project we would have this 2 packages:

- **ProjectName.UI.Buttons**
- **ProjectName.UI.Modals**

**Conclusion**: Write your own namespaces, because Unity namespaces generation is based on folders structure from root and I think that is not the best if you want to share your code by modules, for example.

*Good luck, bro*

Comment: thanks for that but unfortunately I wasn't able to understand completely. The correct settings value for your example should be `Scripts`?

Comment: Personally I prefer /Source folder rather than Scripts. Anyway you can exclude that folder path for the namespaces

Comment: Ok so in the `Assets` folder you have a folder named `Source` containing all the code. Do you set the value `Source` or `./Source`?

Comment: or `Assets/Source` or `./Assets/Source`

Comment: Yes! I have a Source folder and for this example my namespaces would be: ProjectName.UI.Buttons and ProjectName.UI.Modals,im going to edit the answer to include the project name because I forgot it

Comment: I updated my question, maybe this makes things more clear

Comment: I repeat: I suggest you to write your own namespaces because Unity system is a litle weird. Your namespace should be something like ProjectName.UI.Buttons. I think is enough clear!!

Comment: yes I understood but what is the purpose of that feature then ... When setting the value `Assets.Sources` it still does not create the correct namespace. If Unity is not able to provide this I better stick to the old way

Comment: There is nothing perfect in software haha

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Rider , then try [this.](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Refactorings__Adjust_Namespaces.html) Resharper has the same option. I don't use neither of them , so , have to use Select(Assets) + Del everytime making a new class.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the same issue by disabling "Generate Player .csproj files" in editor setting, then deleting the .csproj files and regenerating.